# How can I Integrate Duffel Payments (using UMD module) if I am using Python in the backend?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I don't know how to write the two required functions bellow that can achieve the goes started in the commented text.
API Guidelines: https://duffel.com/docs/guides/collecting-customer-card-payments#collect-payment

[image: The Payment Component]

The API has no examples of implementation.

I want the component to render on the screen. I have managed to generate the payment intent in the flask back-end and pass it to the front-end using flask `render_template()` method as a valuable and then retrieve it in the front end using jinja.  That is all I know. I am a newbie please help me with implementation examples, including how to write:

1. `successfulPaymentHandlerFn`.
2. `errorPaymentFn`.

Answer (score 0):

Backend:

```
import requests
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/create-payment-intent', methods=['POST'])
def create_payment_intent():
    amount = 106.00
    currency = "GBP"
    headers = {
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Duffel-Version': 'v1',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'
    }
    data = {
        'data': {
            'amount': str(amount),
            'currency': currency
        }
    }
    response = requests.post('https://api.duffel.com/payments/payment_intents', headers=headers, json=data)
    payment_intent = response.json()
    return jsonify(payment_intent)
```

Front-end:

```
// This function will be called when the payment is successful
function successfulPaymentHandlerFn(paymentIntentId) {
    // Handle the successful payment
    console.log('Payment successful! PaymentIntent ID:', paymentIntentId);
}

// This function will be called when there is an error during payment
function errorPaymentFn(error) {
    // Handle the payment error
    console.error('Payment error:', error);
}

// Render the payment component
const paymentContainer = document.getElementById('payment-container');
const paymentIntentId = '{{ payment_intent_id }}';  // Retrieve the payment intent ID from your Flask template
const paymentComponent = duffel.payments.createPaymentComponent(paymentIntentId, {
    container: paymentContainer,
    onSuccess: successfulPaymentHandlerFn,
    onError: errorPaymentFn
});
```

Then just:

```
return render_template('payment.html', payment_intent_id=payment_intent['data']['id'])
```

what code can I add to the successfulPaymentHandler to so that when the handler is called it trigers the confirm() function that I will put in the back-end to confirm the payment taking the intent id as the input?

```
successfulPaymentHandlerFn(paymentIntentId) {    
    const confirmPaymentUrl = '/confirm-payment'; 
    const requestData = { paymentIntentId };
    fetch(confirmPaymentUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(requestData)
    })
    .then(response => {
        // Handle the response 
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // Handle the error case
    });
}
```

Backend:

```
@app.route('/confirm-payment', methods=['POST'])
def confirm_payment():
    payment_intent_id = request.json['paymentIntentId']    
// do something with payment_intent_id
    return jsonify({'status': 'success'})
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, and what code can I add to the successfulPaymentHandler to so that when the handler is called it trigers the confirm() function that I will put in the back-end to confirm the payment taking the intent id as the input.

Comment: sure I added more to answer